# How can you get a constant pointer to the first char in a character array?

Tags: c++, string, pointers, c++14

In the following program the string stored is changed using `cin`, thus changing address.
The address of the first element of string is represented by `s`. The address of the first element is the string itself. Thus it got changed when new string is entered. When I try to output `&s[0]` to `cout` it gives the whole string.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    char s[6];
    cin >> s;   // say abcde
    cout << s ; 
    cout << &s[0] ; // gives abcde

    cin >> s;   // say stack 
    cout << s;  
    cout << &s[0] ; gives stack
}
```

Comment: And what address is changing exactly?

Comment: Non sequitur. The string stored in the array is changing. This entails nothing about its address.

Comment: You should really read [a good book on C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list?lq=1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The address is not changing, the data stored at the address is changing. The reason the whole string's getting printed is because you're passing a **pointer** to `cout`, and an array can be passed to a function (or a stream) by giving a pointer to the first item. Passing a pointer to the first char is like passing a C-style string. If you want to print the address of the first char then you need to cast the pointer to `void*`: `cout<<(void*)&s[0]` (this will print the address of the first char).

Comment: @Quentin I fixed that, is it better now?

Comment: @Quentin I'll fix that too, thanks! (seriously) EDIT: Is it better?